# Is it possible to programmatically distinguish between versions of SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Basically, is it possible to identify if some-one hooks up my program to SQL server Compact or Express Edition? I want to be able to restrict different versions of my product to different versions of SQL Server.

Comment: How did you actually do this because none of the responses are supported in SQL Server compact edition? (SQL CE 4)

Comment: none of the proposed solutions work for **SQL Server Compact Edition** (both 3.x and 4.x)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After connection to a database, you can always run the T-Sql:

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY ('edition')
```

This should give you the different editions

Other useful info may come from:

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('productversion'), SERVERPROPERTY ('productlevel')
```

Comment: SERVERPROPERTY is not supported in compact edition 4.  "Error: The function is not recognized by SQL Server Compact. [ Name of function = SERVERPROPERTY,Data type (if known) =  ]"  Neither for that matter are any of the other methods so far posted.  I'm surprised the original poster accepted this answer.  Perhaps it worked in SQL Server Compact Edition 3.x

Answer (score 2):

Run this SQL statement

```
SELECT @@VERSION
```

and it'll give you a ReultSet (one column as a String) with the version like this

> Microsoft SQL Server  2000 - 8.00.760
>   (Intel X86)  Dec 17 2002 14:22:05 
>   Copyright (c) 1988-2003 Microsoft
>   Corporation Standard Edition on
>   Windows NT 5.0 (Build 2195: Service
>   Pack 4)

Comment: The question was about SQL Server compact edition and (at least in version 4) this does not work: Error: "The global variable name @@VERSION is not valid"

Comment: He said compact or express edition. I'm pretty sure it works in express edition. As for compact well I think this might work "var version = typeof(System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection).Assembly.GetName().Version;"

Answer (score 1):

The [**Microsoft Knowledgebase article KB321185**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321185) describes how to identify your current Microsoft SQL Server version number and the corresponding product or service pack level.

It also describes how to identify the specific edition if you are using Microsoft SQL Server 2000 or Microsoft SQL Server 7.0.

Comment: That link does *not* discuss compact edition at all which is the original posters question.

Comment: @JohnC on the other hand, the last sentence "I want to be able to restrict different versions of my product to different versions of SQL Server." and the tag "sql server" is misleading, since the term "SQL Server" is commonly referred as the server product. Since he accepted an answer, I suppose the OP didn't mean the compact version.

Answer (score 0):

There's also the SERVERPROPERTY function that can give you things like 'edition':

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY ('edition')
```

Comment: Not supported by compact edition which was the original posters question.